# SQL: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL Function called `compare_two_regions` that returns the datatype `BIT`, I want to call this function on a function called `compare_two_series`.
I simplified this function to the point where i only want to return the value from the `compare_two_regions` function. Still I would like to call the `compare_two_regions` function under a loop, but even in this simplified case:

```
DELIMITER $$

create function compare_two_series( serieA varchar(255), serieB varchar(255)) 
returns BIT 
begin
declare result BIT;

/*falta ver*/
SELECT P1.x1,P1.y1,P1.x2,P1.y2,P2.x1,P2.y1,P2.x2,P2.y2
FROM region as P1, region as P2
WHERE P1.region.series_id = serieA AND P2.region.series_id = serieB;

SELECT compare_two_regions(P1.x1,P1.y1,P1.x2,P1.y2,P2.x1,P2.y1,P2.x2,P2.y2) into result;
return result;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following error: `Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing this

```
SELECT P1.x1,P1.y1,P1.x2,P1.y2,P2.x1,P2.y1,P2.x2,P2.y2
FROM region as P1, region as P2
WHERE P1.region.series_id = serieA AND P2.region.series_id = serieB;

SELECT compare_two_regions(P1.x1,P1.y1,P1.x2,P1.y2,P2.x1,P2.y1,P2.x2,P2.y2) into result;
```

to this

```
SELECT compare_two_regions(P1.x1,P1.y1,P1.x2,P1.y2,P2.x1,P2.y1,P2.x2,P2.y2) into result
FROM region as P1, region as P2
WHERE P1.region.series_id = serieA AND P2.region.series_id = serieB;
```

It will fail if the result of the query returns more than one row. If you want to use a loop, you will need to set up a cursor.